# Group items with the same value in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, dictionary

I have an array of objects for example

```
const data = [
 {color: "green", number: 23}, 
 {color: "red", number: 25}, 
 {color: "green", number: 27}, 
 {color: "green", number: 26}, 
 {color: "orange", number: 30}
];
```

I wanna group items that are the same based on one value but only if they are one after another and make a dropdown. If there is something in between then no. So for example this would look like this.

```
green
red
green (2)
orange
```

If I click on green that has two items, it shows both, and if I click back on it it shows just number.I tried to do something with bootstrap dropdown but didn't have much luck. How can I group items if they are just one after another and not if there is some value in between them?

Comment: Show your attempt on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't provided any code of your work, let me provide you some, I'm sure that from there you'll be able to build your bootstrap stuff.

Your original Data

```
const data = [
 {color: "green", number: 23}, 
 {color: "red", number: 25}, 
 {color: "green", number: 27}, 
 {color: "green", number: 26}, 
 {color: "orange", number: 30}
];
```

Let's initialize our variables...

```
let previousItemColor = false;
let newData = [];
```

Loop through our original data...

```
data.map((item, index) => {
    // Does our last iteration was about the same color ? 

    // Yes ! ✨
    if (item.color === previousItemColor) {
        // Remove the last entry from newData and store it in lastItem
        let lastItem = newData.pop();
        // Append the new item into lastItem elements property
        lastItem.elements.push(item)
        // Push that modified entry into newData array
        newData.push(lastItem);
    }

    // Oh! That's a new entry 
    else {
        let newEntry = {
            groupName: item.color,
            elements: [item]
        };
        newData.push(newEntry);
    }

    // Don't forget, we need to store that color into peviousItemColor, so our script know what was the last iteration.
    previousItemColor = item.color;
});
```

Let's check if we are on the right way...

```
console.log(newData);
```

Expected results:

```
data = [
    {groupName: "green", elements: [{color: green, number: 23}]},
    {groupName: "red", elements: [{color: red, number: 25}]},
    {groupName: "green", elements: [{color: green, number: 27}, {color: green, number: 26}]},
    {groupName: "orange", elements: [{color: orange, number: 30}]}
];
```

Since we have workable data now, we can build any dropdown we like...

```
newData.map((item, index) => {
        console.log(`${item.groupName} ${(item.elements.length > 1 ? item.elements.length : '')}`);
});
```

Expected results:

```
green
red
green 2
orange
```

With that approach, you still keep all the data you had at the beginning so you can create sub-item in your dropdown.

**P.S. I know there's another way to approach it, but since O.P. look fairly new, let's make it the long way, so he/she understand the whole process.**

Comment: Hy Jonathan, thank you very much for detailed explanation. This worked perfectly.